# BACKUP LOG failed to write to Azure Blob

Tags: azure-vm, azure-blob-storage, azure-sql-server

We have a SQL VM running out of Azure with SQL Agent jobs running BACKUP LOG every x hours
to Azure Blob.  These jobs have been running fine for a long time until recently.  We keep getting
the below error and these jobs fail intermittently for various databases.  They don't always fail
at their scheduled run.  If it fails, I can re-run the job manually like two minutes later
without any issue.  I have looked up online and haven't found a solution to my problem.

Does anyone know why and how I can fix this?  Any help is appreciated.

---

Message
Executed as user: DSN\xyz. Write on "https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/CW_Data_LOG_06102022_140000.TRN"
failed: 13(The data is invalid.) [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3202)  BACKUP LOG is terminating abnormally. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3013).
The step failed.

Comment: Poor network connection? And have you run `DBCC CHECKDB`

Comment: We have Azure ExpressRoute so it's not network.

Comment: That's not strictly true: you could have a BGP or STP flap which is intermittently taking it down, it could even be a poor network cable. Talk to your network engineers. Always check the obvious first.